# Failed to create MD5 hash for file classes.dex

Tags: android, android-instant-run

hey guys i am getting this error when i enable Instant Run I searched , but dint get anything please help

```
Error:org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file'D:\AndroidProjects\EzeeServe\Notification_test\app\build\intermediates\tran
sforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10000\instant-
run_4e106acbedaa2231022cc2be3f931c0f027ccab4\classes.dex'.

Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\AndroidProjects\EzeeServe\Notification_test\app\build\intermediates\transform
s\dex\debug\folders\1000\10000\instant-
run_4e106acbedaa2231022cc2be3f931c0f027ccab4\classes.dex (The system cannot 
find the file specified)
```

Comment: Try setting the gradle project-cache-dir to a different directory.

Comment: the Antivirus is blocking that file from being created,